# Missing / No Symbolicate Crash File

Tags: xcode, xcode7, symbolicatecrash

Apple rejected my app and sent along a few crash files.  I have been trying everything I can to symbolicate these files to no avail.  I think part of the problem may be that I appear to be missing Xcode's symbolicate crash file (see image).  Does anyone know why that is, but more importantly, how I can replace this missing file?

I've considered uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode, but was worried I may lose my Archives or other important information. Link to image of my finder here (Need 10 reputation points before I can directly post an image):

[finder evidencing no symbolicate crash file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIy8Z.png)

Comment: It looks like you're looking for `symbolicatecrash`.  You can find it by running the command `find . -name "symbolicatecrash"` from Terminal in Xcode.app.  On my machine, it's in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash`.

Comment: @NobodyNada Thank you!